# Can option chain data be used as a quick and dirty substitute for proper pricing calculations for non-traded options?

Tags: options, black-scholes

I wonder if the option chain data that is published everyday by websites like Yahoo finance can be used to quickly price options that are not yet traded? So in other words, to estimate option prices in the future?

**For example, can I take the price of a call that is USD 5 in the money *today* and expires in 3 months, as a proxy for a call on that same stock that is USD 5 in the money and expires in 3 months, *9 months from now*. So that I am saying: Price_now = Price_then.**

For example, suppose I have the following information about a 12-month call option and I want to estimate its price 9 months from today. The following data is known:

— spot price of underlying: 50

— strike: 100

— maturity: 12 months

— expected spot price in 9 months: 110

— date of option price of interest: 9 months from today (so it will mature 3 months after that)

Of course I could try to construct a volatility surface and try to interpolate.

But can I price this option by simply taking today’s option chain data for the stock and checking the price of a call with a 3 month maturity (12 -/- 9) that is 10 in-the-money (110 -/- 100)?

Comment: I see option traders use this kind of calculation all the time (playing with the moneyness and maturity). It is not very rigorous though, for example if you use 3 month options now to estimate what a 9 month option will be worth 6 months from now you are implicitly assuming IV will be the same. If you appreciate the shortcomings it may have heuristic value. It is part of the mental tricks that traders use.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, as I understand it, the assumption you would make when doing this is that the implied volatility and risk-free rate of today can be used to estimate the price of "tomorrow". The other elements - strike, spot price, time to maturity - are given.